# Можно ли, и как именно задать точную точку, где будет отоображаться окно в Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

Проблема в том, что когда окно запускается, оно может отрисоваться в рандомном месте. И хотелось бы узнать как можно это можно исправить

Comment: Никак. Это свойство оконного менеджера, и пользователь в своём праве открыть его где угодно (override). Не знаю, правда, насчёт Wayland и GL менеджеров. А ОС-то какая?

Comment: Windows 10 x32, я имел ввиду не то, что оно будет всегда в этих координатах, а то, что оно там откроется(Например слева в углу или посередине)

Comment: Про Windows не знаю, а про Unix я вам уже написал.